# Cannot convert string to datetime datatype using pandas to_datetime method

Tags: python, pandas, string-to-datetime

I'm having a hard time with pd.to_datetime() in Python 3 on Anaconda. Hopefully it's a simple fix, but it's saying that the issue is the data is a series type and not a DataFrame. Can someone please let me know if there's a quick fix to this?

This is the code that's giving me an error:

```
pd.to_datetime(Confirmed_Date_test.ObservationDate, errors='coerce', format='%d%m%Y')
```

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

Here is the code where the data is wrangled:

[image]

Comment: When I use .reset_index, as recommended, I get the following error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-6c150d3816f1> in <module>
----> 1 Confirmed_Date_test.reset_index(inplace=true)

NameError: name 'true' is not defined

Comment: When I use .reset_index() without inplace parameter, it works. The original error remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved by adding .to_frame() to the end of the ln 39.

Answer (score 2):

Observation Date is the index of your groupby result.
Add a reset index before the pd.todatetime():

```
Confirmed_Date_test.reset_index(inplace=true)
```